# VB6 Recordset, Store Record to end of Database

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6

I have a problem with storing new records to a mdb Database in VB6.
If i first store a new record to the Database, the new record is listed at the end of the database. If i then add some other records and delete and re-store the one i've added at the beginning, this is inserted at the index in the list, where it was when I first added this record.

Maybe this is because the record contains the same data as before?

Is there a way, to suppress this behaviour and always add the record at the end of the Database.

Write to Database:

```
Public Function DB_Eintrag_Schreiben(ByVal lSerienummer As Long, ByVal sMacAdr1 As Variant, ByVal sMacAdr2 As Variant, ByVal sMacAdr3 As Variant, ByVal sMacAdr4 As Variant, _
                    ByVal sType As Variant, ByVal sMatNr As Variant, ByVal sAuftrNr As Variant, _
                    ByVal sDatum As Variant, ByVal sZusatzfeld As Variant) As Integer
                    
Dim Db As Database
Dim Tabelle As Recordset
Dim x As Integer


On Error GoTo Errhand

Set Db = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(GetCurDir, False, False)
Set Tabelle = Db.OpenRecordset("Daten")

Tabelle.AddNew
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld1) = lSerienummer
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld2) = CStr(sMacAdr1)
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld3) = CStr(sMacAdr2)
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld4) = CStr(sMacAdr3)
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld5) = CStr(sMacAdr4)
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld6) = CStr(sType)
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld7) = CStr(sMatNr)
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld8) = CStr(sAuftrNr)
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld9) = CStr(sDatum)
Tabelle(sgDatenFeld10) = CStr(sZusatzfeld)
Tabelle.Update

Tabelle.Close
Db.Close
Set Tabelle = Nothing
Set Db = Nothing
DB_Eintrag_Schreiben = 0

Exit Function
```

Delete from Database

```
Public Function DB_Eintrag_Loeschen(lSerienummer As Long) As Boolean
Dim Tabelle As Recordset
Dim Db As Database

On Error GoTo Errhand

' Tabelle öffnen
Set Db = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(GetCurDir, False, False)
Set Tabelle = Db.OpenRecordset("Daten")

'Aktiver Index Festlegen
Tabelle.Index = sgDatenFeld1

'Zur ersten Spalte gehen
If Tabelle.RecordCount > 0 And Not Tabelle.BOF Then
    Tabelle.MoveFirst
End If

' Suchen nach Serienummer
Tabelle.Seek "=", lSerienummer

If Not Tabelle.NoMatch Then
    Tabelle.Delete
    DB_Eintrag_Loeschen = True
Else
    DB_Eintrag_Loeschen = False
End If

Tabelle.Close
Db.Close
Set Tabelle = Nothing
Set Db = Nothing

Exit Function
```

Comment: A database is not a spreadsheet. The order of records in a table is never guaranteed. When you query the table, simply include an Order By clause specifying the order that you desire.

Comment: On the following Webpage it says, that there is a possibility to add the new record to the end of the recordset or am I misunderstanding this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-addnew-method-dao

Comment: _am I misunderstanding this_. Yes. That is for a current recordset not being closed. If you close and open the recordset, it will be sorted by an index, your specified sort order, or - lacking these - whatever order.

Comment: That article indicates record is added to end of recordset. How it shows up in table is not necessarily same. Why are you 'restoring' a record? Why are you passing lSerienummer as an argument of procedure for adding record? Is sgDatenFeld1 an autonumber?

Comment: What @AVG said. SQL databases don't preserve the order of records in a table.

Comment: To add what the others said: if you want to ensure a certain _order_ of the records, you need to introduce a column yourself that holds the value upon which you'd like to sort your data. The most simple way, as already mentioned by @June7, would be to add a column of type AutoNumber. That's simply an Integer value that is automatically incremented by the database itself everytime you add a new record.